# word addin is not loading in word online in any version of internet explorer

Tags: office-js

word addin is not loading in word online in  any version of internet explorer."Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate". This is message is coming.Below i have put manifest.Please suggest.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <!-- BeginBasicSettings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided -->

  <!--IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you clone this manifest ensure that you change this id to your own GUID -->
  <Id>171371dd-52ac-4c34-bab4-c9e27eae5fda</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Parrot365 :: Dev</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various placed of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Parrot365 :: Dev" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Parrot365 :: Dev Mode"/>

  <!--Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog -->
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://p365.wittyparrot.com:3000/resources/assets/images/parrot365/p365_icons/parrot365_32px.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://p365.wittyparrot.com:3000/resources/assets/images/parrot365/p365_icons/parrot365_128px.png" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://support.wittyparrot.com/support/home" />

  <!--BeginTaskpaneMode integration. Office 2013 and any client that doesn't understand commands will use this section.
    This section will also be used if there are no VersionOverrides -->
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Document" />
    <Host Name="Workbook" />
    <Host Name="Presentation" />
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://p365.wittyparrot.com:3000?source=msoffice" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <!--EndTaskpaneMode integration -->

  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>

  <!--BeginAddinCommandsMode integration-->
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <!-- Optional, override the description of the Add-in -->
    <Description resid="residToolTip" />
    <!--Required, hosts node. Each host can have a different set of commands -->
    <Hosts>
      <!--Specific host. Workbook=Excel, Document=Word, Presentation=PowerPoint -->
      <Host xsi:type="Document">
        <!-- Form factor. Currenly only DesktopFormFactor is supported. We will add TabletFormFactor and PhoneFormFactor in the future-->
        <DesktopFormFactor>

          <!--GetStarted information used on the callout that appears when installing the add-in.
            Ensure you have build 16.0.6769 or above for GetStarted section to work-->
          <GetStarted>
      <!--Title of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a ShortString resource -->
      <Title resid="Witty.GetStarted.Title"/>

      <!--Description of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a LongString resource -->
      <Description resid="Witty.GetStarted.Description"/>

      <!--Not used right now but you need to provide a valid resource. We will add code in the future to consume this URL.
       resid points to a Url resource -->
      <LearnMoreUrl resid="Witty.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
    </GetStarted>
    <FunctionFile resid="residDesktopFuncUrl" />
          <!--PrimaryCommandSurface==Main Office Ribbon-->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
   <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <!--Group. Ensure you provide a unique id. Recommendation for any IDs is to namespace using your companyname-->
              <Group id="Witty.Citations.Group1Id1">
                <!--Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                <Label resid="residLabel4" />
                <!--Icons. Required sizes 16,31,80, optional 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. Strongly recommended to provide all sizes for great UX -->
                <!--Use PNG icons and remember that all URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS -->
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon1_32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_80x80" />
                </Icon>


                 <!--Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu" -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button3Id1">
                  <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                  <Label resid="residLabel3" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                    <Title resid="residLabel" />
                     <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource -->
                    <Description resid="residToolTip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon3_32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <!--This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFuncion or ShowTaskpane-->
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <!--Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the taskpane -->
                    <SourceLocation resid="residUnitConverterUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>

                <!--Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu" -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.FunctionButton">
                <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                  <Label resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                     <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                    <Title resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Label" />
                     <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource -->
                    <Description resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Icon" />
                  </Icon>
                  <!--This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFuncion or ShowTaskpane-->
                  <!--Look at the FunctionFile.html page for reference on how to implement the function -->
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                  <!--Name of the function to call. This function needs to exist in the global DOM namespace of the function file-->
                    <FunctionName>openDialogAsIframe</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>



              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>

      <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
        <!-- Form factor. Currenly only DesktopFormFactor is supported. We will add TabletFormFactor and PhoneFormFactor in the future-->
        <DesktopFormFactor>

          <!--GetStarted information used on the callout that appears when installing the add-in.
            Ensure you have build 16.0.6769 or above for GetStarted section to work-->
          <GetStarted>
      <!--Title of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a ShortString resource -->
      <Title resid="Witty.GetStarted.Title"/>

      <!--Description of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a LongString resource -->
      <Description resid="Witty.GetStarted.Description"/>

      <!--Not used right now but you need to provide a valid resource. We will add code in the future to consume this URL.
       resid points to a Url resource -->
      <LearnMoreUrl resid="Witty.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
    </GetStarted>
    <FunctionFile resid="residDesktopFuncUrl" />
          <!--PrimaryCommandSurface==Main Office Ribbon-->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
   <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <!--Group. Ensure you provide a unique id. Recommendation for any IDs is to namespace using your companyname-->
              <Group id="Witty.Citations.Group1Id1">
                <!--Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                <Label resid="residLabel4" />
                <!--Icons. Required sizes 16,31,80, optional 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. Strongly recommended to provide all sizes for great UX -->
                <!--Use PNG icons and remember that all URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS -->
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon1_32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_80x80" />
                </Icon>
                 <!--Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu" -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button3Id1">
                  <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                  <Label resid="residLabel3" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                    <Title resid="residLabel" />
                     <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource -->
                    <Description resid="residToolTip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon3_32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <!--This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFuncion or ShowTaskpane-->
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <!--Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the taskpane -->
                    <SourceLocation resid="residUnitConverterUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>

      <Host xsi:type="Presentation">
        <!-- Form factor. Currenly only DesktopFormFactor is supported. We will add TabletFormFactor and PhoneFormFactor in the future-->
        <DesktopFormFactor>

          <!--GetStarted information used on the callout that appears when installing the add-in.
            Ensure you have build 16.0.6769 or above for GetStarted section to work-->
          <GetStarted>
      <!--Title of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a ShortString resource -->
      <Title resid="Witty.GetStarted.Title"/>

      <!--Description of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a LongString resource -->
      <Description resid="Witty.GetStarted.Description"/>

      <!--Not used right now but you need to provide a valid resource. We will add code in the future to consume this URL.
       resid points to a Url resource -->
      <LearnMoreUrl resid="Witty.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
    </GetStarted>
    <FunctionFile resid="residDesktopFuncUrl" />
          <!--PrimaryCommandSurface==Main Office Ribbon-->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
   <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <!--Group. Ensure you provide a unique id. Recommendation for any IDs is to namespace using your companyname-->
              <Group id="Witty.Citations.Group1Id1">
                <!--Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                <Label resid="residLabel4" />
                <!--Icons. Required sizes 16,31,80, optional 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. Strongly recommended to provide all sizes for great UX -->
                <!--Use PNG icons and remember that all URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS -->
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon1_32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_80x80" />
                </Icon>
                 <!--Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu" -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button3Id1">
                  <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                  <Label resid="residLabel3" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                    <Title resid="residLabel" />
                     <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource -->
                    <Description resid="residToolTip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon3_32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <!--This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFuncion or ShowTaskpane-->
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <!--Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the taskpane -->
                    <SourceLocation resid="residUnitConverterUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon1_16x16" DefaultValue="https://p365.wittyparrot.com:3000/resources/assets/images/parrot365/p365_icons/parrot365_16px.png">
        </bt:Image>
        <bt:Image id="icon1_32x32" DefaultValue="https://p365.wittyparrot.com:3000/resources/assets/images/parrot365/p365_icons/parrot365_32px.png">
        </bt:Image>
        <bt:Image id="icon1_80x80" DefaultValue="https://p365.wittyparrot.com:3000/resources/assets/images/parrot365/p365_icons/parrot365_48px.png">
        </bt:Image>
      <bt:Image id="icon2_32x32" DefaultValue="https://p365.wittyparrot.com:3000/resources/assets/images/parrot365/p365_icons/parrot365_32px.png">
        </bt:Image>
        <bt:Image id="icon3_32x32" DefaultValue="https://p365.wittyparrot.com:3000/resources/assets/images/parrot365/p365_icons/parrot365_32px.png">
        </bt:Image>
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.FunctionButton.Icon" DefaultValue="https://p365.wittyparrot.com:3000/resources/assets/images/parrot365/p365_icons/parrot365_32px.png" >
        </bt:Image>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
   <bt:Url id="residDesktopFuncUrl" DefaultValue="https://p365.wittyparrot.com:3000?source=msoffice/external-plugin/witty-command-execution/commandExecutionFromRibbon.js">
        </bt:Url>
        <bt:Url id="residUnitConverterUrl" DefaultValue="https://p365.wittyparrot.com:3000?source=msoffice">
        </bt:Url>
          <!--LearnMore URL currently not used -->
        <bt:Url id="Witty.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://p365.wittyparrot.com:3000">
        </bt:Url>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="residLabel" DefaultValue="Launch Widget">
        </bt:String>
        <bt:String id="residLabel3" DefaultValue="Parrot365">
        </bt:String>
        <bt:String id="residLabel4" DefaultValue=" ">
        </bt:String>
        <bt:String id="Witty.GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Parrot365 Widget Loaded Successfully">
        </bt:String>
        <bt:String id="Contoso.FunctionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Save Document into Witty Parrot">
        </bt:String>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="residToolTip" DefaultValue="Parrot365 add-in provides improves productivity, accuracy and consistency in communication.">
        </bt:String>
         <bt:String id="Witty.GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Get going by opening the Home tab on the Ribbon then click Parrot365 button">
        </bt:String>
        <bt:String id="Contoso.FunctionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Execute Function" ></bt:String>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 2):

For production: Ensure a valid, trusted, SSL Certificate is in place on your domain (note that you either need a wildcard cert like *.wittyparrot.com or p365.wittyparrot.com, a certificate for wittyparrot.com doesn't apply to the subdomain).

For dev/test: You may be able to navigate to one of your add in pages in IE and accept whatever warnings are in place, then use the add-in.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your add-in is signed with a digital certificate:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Digital-signatures-and-certificates-8186cd15-e7ac-4a16-8597-22bd163e8e96?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361(VS.85).aspx

https://www.add-in-express.com/docs/net-deployment-considerations.php

Make sure your webpage is certified with a SSL certificate (https): https://certbot.eff.org/

Comment: This is about Office.JS API Add-in, which is just web app and doesn't needs to be signed.